# map v.s. flatmap when promise is involved

Tags: rxjs, reactivex

I am studying

- operator `map` v.s. `flatmap`
- how to add promise into observable chain.

Then I constructed 4 different versions of `var source` as below. 
version 1, 3 works as expected, while version 2, 4 fail oddly.

My code has also been added in => [js bin](http://jsbin.com/sisepiveta/1/edit?html,js,console,output)

Could someone tell what is wrong with my code?

Thanks,
Xi

```
console.clear();
var p = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  setTimeout( () => {
    resolve('resolved!');
  } , 1000);
});

var source = Rx.Observable.interval(200).take(3)
.flatMap(x => Rx.Observable.timer(500).map(() => x))   //version 1, works OK
// .flatMap(x => Rx.Observable.timer(500).map((x) => x))  // version 2, not OK, returns => 0, 0, 0
// .map(x => p.then( s => console.log(s)));                  // version 3, works OK 
// .flatMap(x => p.then( s => console.log(s)));                  // version 4, not OK, error occurs


source.subscribe(x => console.log(x.toString()));
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
.flatMap(x => Rx.Observable.timer(500).map((x) => x))
```

returns "0", "0", "0" because `timer` emits 0 after 500 ms and `map` takes that value as input `x` and returns it with `(x) => x`. In the previous line, `x` was not redeclared in the `map`, so it came from `flatMap`.

```
.flatMap(x => p.then( s => console.log(s)));
```

gives an error because a promise emits the return value of the `then` callback. That's `console.log(s)` which being a statement evaluates to undefined. So the `flatMap` gives an Observable of undefined, undefined, undefined. When the first reaches the `subscribe` it tries to do `undefined.toString` and errors out.

Comment: Thanks, I got the version 2. 
But version 4 is still confusing. If you test the `js bin` code, the output is:  the promise resolves successfully for the first 3 times and then error comes.

Comment: the output for version 4 is

```


"resolved!"
"resolved!"
"resolved!"
"error"
"Script error. (line 0)"
```

Comment: The flatMap executes 3 times its callback. In each one, a new `then` is attached to the same promise `p`. When `p` resolves, the 3 `then` callbacks are executed printing "resolved" 3 times.

Comment: But what goes into `subscribe`? `p.then` returns a promise that is immediately resolved with the return value of the `then` callback. The `then` callback returns the evaluation of `console.log(s)`. That's a statement with no return value, so its evaluation gives undefined. These 3 promises are converted to 3 observables and then flattened by `flatMap`. So in the end, you get an observable that emits undefined 3 times. When the `subscribe` callback is executed for the first time, `x` is undefined. You do `x.toString` and that errors out, killing the observable.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation. I still need a bit time to get my head around this, nevertheless your answer shall be marked as solution, appreciated!